# Magento 2 :- Custom module menus are not showing in another user account

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, custom

I want to show a menu to another user.
acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Tyres_Faq::tyres_faq" title="Faq" sortOrder="51">
                    <resource id="Tyres_Faq::index" title="Index" sortOrder="10"/>
                    <resource id="Tyres_Faq::tyres_faq_configuration" title="Configuration" sortOrder="99" />
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Tyres_Faq::tyres_faq_config" title="Faq"/>
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Menu.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Tyres_Faq" title="Faq" module="Tyres_Faq" sortOrder="90" resource="Tyres_Faq::sample"/>
        <add id="Tyres_Faq::tyres_faq" title="Items" module="Tyres_Faq" sortOrder="10" parent="Tyres_Faq" action="tyres_faq/items/" resource="Tyres_Faq::items"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Menus are not showing in another user account.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your resource name is `Tyres_Faq::tyres_faq_configuration` then you need to check same in your _`isAllowed()` method

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Tyres_Faq::tyres_faq_configuration');
}
```

I also recommend to set id and resource attributes in menu.xml with same values `Tyres_Faq::tyres_faq_configuration`